# Amend option only, no commit and push option in Android Studio 4.2.2

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I had recently updated to Android studio 4.2.2 When I was about to commit, it shows only ammend option. I had looked everywhere but there is no amend and push option. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is the ask here if you can do one button click instead of two? (I'm not familiar with the tool but I assume there is still a push button somewhere...)

Comment: There was a push-button since the first version of the product. I have been using this for more than five years. The new update has some major changes and I was not able to see this in the changelog of the update. That's why I had raised this question here.

Comment: OK. Perhaps someone who also recently upgraded can confirm if it's also missing or still there.